# Subscript error: sum = sum(s)

Tags: octave

Below is my code, where `h` and `Y` are `47x1` vectors.

```
s = h-Y;
sum = sum(s);
```

I am getting this error:

> error: sum(6057.48): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals

Can somebody please explain why?

Comment: "sum = sum(..)", I know nothing about octave but could there be a problem with the naming here? Would "sum =" mean that you redefine the identifier "sum" to be something, and then the interpreter/compiler complains that "identifier(x)" requires x to be integers or logicals? Could you try just `something = sum(s)` ?

Comment: You overshadowed the built-in `sum` function with a newly created `sum` variable. Never ever name a variable or function that is also a built-in function

Comment: getting the same error even after changing the name. @SardarUsama

Comment: `clear` your workspace first.

Comment: clear as in make all the variables again? @SardarUsama

Comment: @AshishGoel `clear sum`

Comment: thanks, it worked. but why? @beaker

Comment: The reason is already explained in my first comment

Comment: Your code 'sum' accept it as a function, but you meant it is your variable, so that is your mistake.

Comment: i understand that. but why do I have to clear sum before defining another variable?

Comment: Because the *built-in* *`sum`* *function* was *over-shadowed*

Comment: @AshishGoel Because your version of `sum` still existed. You had to clear that version of `sum` before the built-in could be reached.

Comment: so if I have a mistake in my code, I can't continue without clearing it? I thought I only run one line not the whole program. Sorry I'm new to programming.

Comment: okay. thanks. I understand it now. @beaker

Comment: The best way to learn the code is to practice it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments by *Sardar Usama*, you cannot use the variable name `sum` when you also want to use the built-in function `sum`.

By default, `sum` is a function, used as you expected it to work in your script.

In Octave, you are permitted to overshadow a built-in function, for instance

```matlab
sum = 4; % Now there is a workspace variable, sum, with the value 4
```

When you do this, **the keyword `sum` now stands for the variable, not the function**. It's strongly advisable not to overwrite default functions, even if you're not planning on using them in that script!

---

To remove your overshadowing, just clear the variable,

```matlab
clear sum % Now it should behave as expected.
```

The reason you must clear the variable before continuing is to do with your workspace. The variable `sum` remains in your workspace even after the program exited, so when you run it again (even if you've chosen a new variable name) you have still already changed how `sum` is interpreted. By clearing the variable, Octave sets it back to its default behaviour as it is removed from your workspace.

---

Summary: use a different variable name.

```matlab
s = h-Y;
mysum = sum(s); % mysum isn't a built-in, so no clashes here!
```