# Octave: Subscripts for the text function?

Tags: text, octave

I'm running Octave 5.1.0. I try to reproduce the code on this page:
https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/text.html

For example, I try to reproduce Demonstration 3 there, i.e. this code:

```
 clf;
 axis ([0 8 0 8]);
 title (["1st title";"2nd title"]);
 xlabel (["1st xlabel";"2nd xlabel"]);
 ylabel (["1st ylabel";"2nd ylabel"]);
 text (4, 4, {"Hello", "World"}, ...
       "horizontalalignment", "center", ...
       "verticalalignment", "middle");
 grid on;
```

I get the following error message:

**text(*,*,,*,*,*,*): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals (note: variable 'text' shadows function)**

I tried changing the code to:

```
clf;
 axis ([0 8 0 8]);
 title (['1st title';'2nd title']);
 xlabel (['1st xlabel';'2nd xlabel']);
 ylabel (['1st ylabel';'2nd ylabel']);
 text (4, 4, 'Hello','horizontalalignment', 'center','verticalalignment', 'middle');
 grid on;
```

Then I get the following error message:

**text(4...[x6]...): but text has size 1x39 (note: variable 'text' shadows function)**

I'm a bit stumped as to how to solve this. I also fail to reproduce other code with the text function. I started running Octave a few weeks ago, so it wouldn't be impossible that my installation failed somehow. Other functions work as expected though.

I have installed the io and statistics packages. Can they interfer somehow?

Can anybody figure out what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscript error: sum = sum(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744125/subscript-error-sum-sums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the error message:

> note: variable 'text' shadows function

It means you have defined "text" as a variable in your workspace, and have assigned a value to it.

Therefore, now each time you try to access the `text` function, you are accessing your variable instead.

Clear your workspace (or just the `text` variable) and try again.

PS. While this is not conventional practice, I personally tend to name all my non-function variables starting with a capital letter, to avoid name-clashes with functions, since most functions in octave start with a small letter.

In general, always check that a name is not taken before you assign something to that name, to avoid 'shadowing' as in this case.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the tip about naming non-function variables! I will use it.